# Unable to Set Cookie with `cookie-parser` in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I have installed `cookie-parser` with Express to use within my React application. I'm trying to set a cookie so that I can begin looking into sessions for a login system.

When setting a cookie with the code below, the console log will only ever output `Cookies: {}`. I'm unable to get a cookie to set.

**cookies.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('test-cookie', 'test-value', {
        maxAge: 60000
    });
    console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies);
})

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using `fetch('/cookies')` to call `cookies.js` from my `app.js` main file.

When refreshing my application, the console log outputs `Cookies: {}`. I cannot see a cookie set within the developer tools `Application` tab either.

Is there any reason I'm unable to set cookies?

Comment: Presumably you actually complete the request at some point?

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply. Could you expand? Sorry I'm brand new to Express.

Answer (score 0):

If I add the following to `fetch('/cookies')`, the cookie is then set:

```
fetch('/cookies', {
    credentials: 'include'
})
```